# Solomon Islands - Ferry ticket Honiara to Auki and back

Tags: solomon-islands

I want to take the ferry from Honiara to Auki in December around Christmas, and back from Auki to Honiara.

1. Can I buy a ticket on the ferry, or do I have to do this beforehand? If the latter, where would I go to buy the ticket?
2. Would tickets sell out in December (esp. around Christmas and New Year)?

Comment: There's a description of the ticket-buying procedure on the [WikiVoyage page for the Solomon Islands](https://en.m.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Solomon_Islands) (see the "Get Around" section). No idea how current that information is, though.

Comment: Facebook pages for two Honiara ferry companies - [Franjti Shipping Ltd](https://www.facebook.com/people/Franjti-Shipping-Ltd/100084020251022/) and [Fairwest Shipping](https://www.facebook.com/people/Fairwest-Shipping/100083958981397/) - you could try contacting them directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pelican service](https://m.facebook.com/pelicanshippinglimited/) has stopped for many months now. This means the other ferry services can become more busy. **Franjti** might be the best option for Auki, the schedule:
[image: Franjti Schedule]

On very busy days they add a ship though, so I'm **100%** sure you are safe if you don't book in advance. E-mail them if you want to be 101% sure though: shipping@franjti.com.sb, but anyway just be there early and you'll make the crossing!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm planning to travel from Honiara to Auki on Monday 25 December, which is Christmas Day. Would that be regarded as a "rest day", or would the ferry do its normal Monday schedule?